# Lua string to table

Tags: string, lua

I have a string that I need to read as a table

```
    notes = "0,5,10,16"
```

so if I need the 3rd value of the current notes that is 10

```
    value = notes[3]
```

Comment: This works http://lua-users.org/wiki/SplitJoin : 
function string:split(sep)
   local sep, fields = sep or ":", {}
   local pattern = string.format("([^%s]+)", sep)
   self:gsub(pattern, function(c) fields[#fields+1] = c end)
   return fields
end

testAsTable = notes.split(notes, ',')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the example string, you can just do

```lua
local notes_tab = {}
for note in notes:gmatch("%d*") do
   table.insert(notes_tab, tonumber(note))
end
```

Comment: I get error: attempt to call a string value (local 'note')

Comment: Fixed; I changed a variable name at the wrong place ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you trust the strings, you can reuse the Lua parser:

```
notes = "0,5,10,16"
notes = load("return {"..notes.."}")()
print(notes[3])
```

Answer (score 1):

We can change the `__index` metamethod of all strings to return the nth element separated by commas. Doing this, however, gives the problem that we cannot do something like `notes:gmatch(",?1,?")` anymore. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18168531/changing-metatable-in-lua-breaks-colon-operator) old StackOverflow post. It can be solved, by checking whether the __index is called with a string or other value.

```
notes = "0,5,10,16"

getmetatable("").__index = function(str, key)
    if type(key) == "string" then
        return string[key]
    else
        next_value = string.gmatch(str, "[^,]+")
        for i=1, key - 1 do
            next_value()
        end
        return next_value()
    end
end

print(notes[3])  --> 10
```

`string.gmatch` returns a function over which we can iterate, so calling this *n* times will result in the nth number being returned.
The for loop makes sure that all the numbers before which we want have been iterated over by the gmatch.
Depending on what you want to do with the numbers you can either return it as a string or convert it to a number immediately.

Comment: This isn't a very efficient approach, however. It does not store any of the numbers for later use, so when you call it often you should indeed just store them separately.