# LUA: How to Create 2-dimensional array/table from string

Tags: lua

I see several posts about making a string in to a lua table, but my problem is a little different [I think] because there is an additional dimension to the table.

I have a table of tables saved as a file [i have no issue reading the file to a string].

let's say we start from this point:
`local tot = "{{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}}"`

When I try the answers from other users I end up with:
 `local OneDtable = {"{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}"}`

This is not what i want.

how can i properly create a table, that contains those tables as entries?
Desired result:

`TwoDtable = {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}}`

Thanks in advance

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/58550387/107090

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the load function to read the content of your string as Lua code.

```
local myArray = "{{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}}"
local convert = "myTable = " .. myArray
local convertFunction = load(convert)
convertFunction()
print(myTable[1][1])
```

Now, myTable has the values in a 2-dimensional array.

Comment: This is beautiful - thanks, I didn't know about that one.  I'm just starting my Lua journey.... its a fun one.

Answer (score 1):

For a quick solution I suggest going with the `load` hack, but be aware that this only works if your code happens to be formatted as a Lua table already. Otherwise, you'd have to parse the string yourself.

For example, you could try using lpeg to build a recursive parser. I built something very similar a while ago:

```lua
local lpeg = require 'lpeg'

local name = lpeg.R('az')^1 / '\0'
local space = lpeg.S('\t ')^1

local function compile_tuple(...)
  return string.char(select('#', ...)) .. table.concat{...}
end

local expression = lpeg.P {
  'e';
  e = name + lpeg.V 't';
  t = '(' * ((lpeg.V 'e' * ',' * space)^0 * lpeg.V 'e') / compile_tuple * ')';
}

local compiled = expression:match '(foo, (a, b), bar)'

print(compiled:byte(1, -1))
```

Its purpose is to parse things in quotes like the example string `(foo, (a, b), bar)` and turn it into a binary string describing the structure; most of that happens in the `compile_tuple` function though, so it should be easy to modify it to do what you want.

What you'd have to adapt:

- change `name` for `number` (and change the pattern accordingly to `lpeg.R('09')^1`, without the `/ '\0'`)
- change the `compile_tuple` function to a `build_table` function (`local function build_tanle(...) return {...} end` should do the trick)
- Try it out and see if something else needs to be changed; I might have missed something.

You can read the lpeg manual [here](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/lpeg/) if you're curious about how this stuff works.

Comment: Thanks for this - it's more than I need at the moment though.  Keep it in the back pocket for sure.