# Find padded hex (0xXX) in Lua string pattern

Tags: string, lua, hex, lua-patterns

I have a Lua string...

```lua
str = "test,0x00,0x34,0x23"
```

and I want to find two elements within this string:

1. The alphanumeric part (test)
2. The comma separated hex values (0xXX)

I'm using the following pattern, which works...

```lua
_,_,a,b = string.find(str,"^(%a+),([x%x,]+)$")
print(a,b)

-->    test    0x00,0x34,0x23
```

However, I want to catch errors, for example, malformed hex representations.

For example, using the above pattern example, it allows and successfully returns the following inputs:

```lua
str = "test,0x0x0,0x34,0x23"   -->    test    0x0x0,0x34,0x23
str = "test,0x00,34,0x23"      -->    test    0x00,34,0x23
str = "test,0x00,0x34,23x0"    -->    test    0x00,0x34,23x0
```

What pattern is needed to only accept valid padded hex form (`string.format("0x%02x",72)`) please?

Comment: `local a,b = str:match("^(%w+)([x%x,]+)$"); if a and b:gsub(",0x%x%x", "") == "" then print(a, b) end`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/58550387/107090