# How would I convert a string into a table?

Tags: lua, lua-table

I have been trying to convert a string into a table for example:

```
local stringtable = "{{"user123","Banned for cheating"},{"user124","Banned for making alt accounts"}}"
```

Code:

```
local table = "{{"user123","Banned for cheating"},{"user124","Banned for making alt accounts"}}"

print(table[1])
```

Output result:

```
Line 3: nil
```

Is there any sort of method of converting a string into a table? If so, let me know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58532468/lua-string-to-table. See my answer there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58550387/107090

Comment: Your question isn't clear. None of the code you provided is valid Lua code, so it's hard to tell what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: String to table or table to string?

Comment: String to table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your Lua code will not work. You cannot have unescaped double quotes in a string delimited by double quotes. Use single quotes(`'`) within a `"`-string, `"` within `'...'` or use heredoc syntax to be able to use both types of quotes, as shall I in the example below.

Secondly, your task cannot be solved with a regular expression, unless your table structure is very rigid; and even then Lua patterns will not be enough: you will need to use Perl-compatible regular expressions from Lua *lrexlib* library.

Thirdly, fortunately, Lua has a Lua interpreter available at runtime: the function [loadstring](https://www.lua.org/pil/8.html). It returns a function that executes Lua code in its argument string. You just need to prepend `return` to your table code and call the returned function.

The code:

```lua
local stringtable = [===[
{{"user123","Banned for cheating"},{"user124","Banned for making alt accounts"}}
]===]

local tbl_func = loadstring ('return ' .. stringtable)
-- If stringtable is not valid Lua code, tbl_func will be nil:
local tbl = tbl_func and tbl_func() or nil

-- Test:
if tbl then
    for _, user in ipairs (tbl) do
        print (user[1] .. ': ' .. user[2])
    end
else
    print 'Could not compile stringtable'
end
```